# VBA:: intersect vs. match method

Tags: vba, match, intersect

I had a question pertaining to the two built in VBA function of .Match and .Intersect.  Currently I have 2 1-dimensional arrays that I wish to consolidate information into a new array.  I realize I've posted a question about the approach to the problem earlier but this question pertains to which method would be better.  Would one way be able to consolidate information into a new array faster than the other? and is one method more reliable than the other as well?

Comment: between using match or intersect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Excel help

> Excel Developer Reference
>
> Application.Intersect Method
> Returns a Range object that represents the rectangular intersection of two or more ranges.

Arrays are not ranges, so interset is not applicable to your question as stated.

A more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do, and what form your raw data is in will allow better advice

Answer (score 0):

If you are merging your two arrays in vba, then the `.Match` function and the `.Intersect` do not behave the same way because, you won't be able to *merge* with a `Match` function, you will only be able to *find* a value.

Hence, i would say, use **intersect** method.

If you want a more precise answer, please tell us more precisely what you want to do with your arrays with examples and the code you already built.

Regards,

Max

Comment: @Max I want to extract the values that are duplicated in the arrays and build a new array to contain the duplicated values. I have created a function using .Match  but am experiencing some problems with it.  I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504018/vba-subscript-error

Answer (score 0):

Intersect is a method for finding the intersection of one or more ranges: it won't work with arrays. It returns the subset range that is the intersection of the range arguments.
Unless your arrays are sorted it would probably be more efficient to just loop compare the arrays than use .MATCH